Takes 2 times to authenticate using RDP
I have a domain controller running on hyper V. If I RDP into it, first I get the RDP credentials and then it opens the RDP session but it keeps asking for signin credentials again. Most just use the credentials provided by the 1st user/pass input on RDP. I would assume this is a gpedit.msc enable/disable function. Any clues? The remote computer is Server 2016.
At first no one could remote into this machine after hours of troubleshooting, the following worked:
go to search and type gpedit.msc Computer Config>Admin Templates>Windows Components>Remote Desktop Services>Remote Desktop Session Host>Connections>
Enable Allow users to connect remotely by using Remote Desktop Services
Then go to Computer Config>Admin Templates>Windows Components>Remote Desktop Services>Remote Desktop Session Host>Security>
Disable    Require user authentication for remote connections by using Network Level Authentication
Check this by the following:
Open Regedit
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Terminal Services
UserAuthentication = 0
